# How does Accelerated Aging effect Lenara Kahn with an Engineering Pad

Tags: star-trek-ccg

My opponent has a [Lenara Kahn](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=90) (whose first listed skill is Astrometrics) in her team, together with an [Engineering Pad](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=511) (which gives all Engineers, like Lenara, Astrometrics).

On a mission attempt I play [Accelerated Aging](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=2003) (which makes the first listed skill unusable).

Now its unclear to us what happens:

Either the Padd goes first (that means she had 2 Astrometrics) and the Aging removed that skill from her list (so she had none left).
-> This argumentation says that as she already had the Padd with her on the mission attempt, the addition must come first.

Or the Aging goes first which removed her Astrometrics and then the Padd which gave it back to her (so she ends up with 1 Astrometrics).
-> This argumentation says that the Padd is active only when required, so it adds an Astrometrics in the end.

Comment: You say aging removed the skill, but it doesn't. It just presents it being used. Lenara still has the upgraded skill but can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/rulings.php?mode=view&ruling=464) ruling we read (emphasis mine):

> When a personnel gains a skill that is not printed on his or her card, that skill is not inserted anywhere into that personnel's listed skills and is therefore unaffected by Accelerated Aging.
>
> However, **if a personnel gains an additional level of a printed skill he or she already has, that printed skill can still be affected by Accelerated Aging.**

Given that Lenara Kahn already has Astrometrics (that is, it's already printed on her card), it seems that **Accelerated Aging will affect her**.

*Disclaimer*: I was not so familiar with this game, but did quite some reading and searching. Still, open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the text of the card (since I'm not familiar with the game), Accelerated Aging doesn't remove Astrometrics from Lenara Kahn as you claim; it just prevents her from using it.

So, even if she's affected by Accelerated Aging, Lenara Kahn has Astrometrics, and the Engineering Pad will therefore simply increase the level of that skill for her.